# Linux cpu-to-cpu inter-process communications

Tags: linux, ipc

I have written a Linux C program, which runs on an embedded processor, and which behaves like a shell -- either interactively, giving a prompt, parsing user commands, and executing them, in an indefinite loop, or non-interactively -- reading and parsing a command off the invocation command. I want to run the same program concurrently on another embedded processor, which is reachable using e/net (e.g. ssh), and use it for some commands because the second processor has access to some hardware that the first processor does not. I usually need to capture and process the outputs from that remote command. Currently, I invoke the program on the second processor for each command -- e.g.

```
system ("ssh other-cpu my_program "do this command > /vtmp/out_capt");
system ("scp other-cpu:/vtmp/out_capt .")
```

This works, but it is slow. Is there a better way, perhaps using pipes? If someone could point me to their pick of a best way to do this kind of IPC I would appreciate it.

Comment: If you want to use `ssh` for this you should use at least `ControlMaster` and `ControlPersist`. But if it is secure environment, you can skip to encryption and use different protocol (though unfortunately I don't have any recommendation here).

Answer (score 0):

You could get rid of `scp` and just save the output from ssh on the local machine. Something like this:

```
ssh other-cpu '( my_program command )' > file.log
```

Or if you want to run multiple commands:

```
ssh other-cpu > file.log << EOF
my_program command
my_program other_command
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this, with varying speed and complexity. [Naturally :-)], the fastest requires the most setup.

---

(1) You can replace your two command sequence with an output pipe.

You create a single pipe via `pipe(2)`. You do a `fork(2)`. The child attaches the output fildes of the pipe to stdout. The child does `execvp("ssh","remote","my_program","blah")`. The parent reads the results from the input fildes of the pipe. No need for a temp file.

This is similar to what you're currently doing in that you do an `ssh` for each remote command you want to execute, but eliminating the temp file and the `scp`.

---

(2) You can modify `my_program` to accept various commands from `stdin`. I believe you already do this in the program's "shell" mode.

You create *two* pipes via `pipe(2)`. Again, `fork` a child. Attach the output fildes of the "from_remote" pipe as before to `stdout`. But, now, attach the input fildes of the "to_remote" pipe to `stdin`.

In the parent, using the fildes for output of the "to_remote" pipe, send a command line. The remote reads this line [via the input fildes of the "to_remote" pipe, parses it the way a shell would, and fork/execs the resulting command.

After the child program on the remote has terminated, my_program can output a separater line.

The parent reads the data as before until it sees this separater line.

Now, any time the local wants to do something on the remote, the pipes are already set up. It can just write subsequent commands to the output fildes of the "to_remote" pipe and repeat the process.

Thus, no teardown and recreation required.  Only one `ssh` needs to be set up. This is similar to setting up a server with a socket, but we're using `ssh` and pipes.

If the local wishes to close the connection, it can close the pipe on its end [or send a (e.g.) "!!!stop" command]

If your remote target commands are text based, the separater is relatively easy (i.e. some string that none of your programs would ever output like: `_jsdfl2_werou_tW__987_`).

If you've got raw binary data, my_program may have to filter/encapsulate the data in some way (e.g. similar to what the `PPP` protocol does with its `flag` character)

---

(3) You can create a version of `my_program` (e.g. `my_program -server`) that acts like a server that listens on a socket [in shell mode].

The "protocol" is similar to case (2) above, but may be a bit easier to set up because a network socket is inherently bidirectional (vs. the need for *two* `pipe(2)` calls above).

One advantage here is that you're communicating directly over a TCP socket, bypassing the overhead of the encryption layer.

You can either start the remote server at boot time or you can use a [one-time] `ssh` invocation to kick it off into the background.

There is one additional advantage. Instead of the "separater line" above, the local could make a separate socket connection to the server for each command. This is still slower than above, but faster than creating the `ssh` on each invocation.

Comment: Sorry, but I have to thank Craig Estey especially, even if thanking is verboten. I am very satisfied with the answer and the direction it has pointed me.

Comment: You're welcome. Thanking in a comment is [technically] verboten, but it's done all the time. Another way to express thanks is to upvote the answer and/or "accept" the answer as correct/best one. These give the answerer the "reputation points". This is _encouraged_ by SO/stackexchange in general [and me, here, in particular--shameless plug ;-)]